# Banga Sauce Preservative

Tags: sauce

Ripe and mature Palm fruits.  Boil soft and pound to get   paste,  remove some palm oil,  then filter to get banga Sauce. How  do I get a long shief life Preservative.?

Comment: Even though it is unlikely that somebody can recommend a "stir in and forget" preservative - knowing the exact recipe (the amount of oils, salt, sugars and water in a recipe are immensely important when it comes to shelf life, with or without synthetic preservatives added) and intended storage conditions will certainly help.

Comment: Banga Sauce without sugar or salt.  To be canned like Tin Tomatoes  or placed in Satchet to be kept iSn

Comment: Three quater of the oil content will be extracted. Just  a little quantity of Water to have it tick like tin Tomatoes.

Comment: Even if somebody on this site was to give you advice on how to can and preserve a commercial product, you should not trust that advice. This is a site of amateur and professional cooks and bakers, so while some might have professional competence on how to cook and serve food safely, commercial processing and preservation is a different area of knowledge, any advice on commercial preservation techniques you will have to double check with professionals that you know by name and can hold responsible.

Comment: If there is anyone on this site with commercial experience with strong (200 series E numbers) preservatives - I AM NOT - that person should be found and encouraged to write a canonical ....

Answer (score 5):

If this is for a commercial product, talk to a distributor/maker of preservatives directly and discuss your exact product - be prepared for them mandating changes to the recipe. They will also know what your local laws (and the laws of any intended target market) allow or do not allow.

Consider consulting academic/professional literature on food preservation - but in the end, unless you are formally trained expert in these things, it is best to keep the responsibility with the food additive maker as much as possible.

If this is for home preservation, if no known good recipes for a shelf stable version exist, the effort needed to create one is not unlikely to be too high to be worth it - and mistakes when experimenting with chemical preservatives (benzoates, nitrates....) can yield harmful product that makes you or your family sick.

There is no "stir in enough poison to make bacteria dead and leave us alive" solution that works for all foods and storage conditions. Using a chemical preservative in the wrong way can result in a product that does not visibly spoil but turns poisonous (eg by botulism) because you killed everything that could stop it from doing so - or which is poisonous due to overdosing the preservative.

Comment: Please it is for commercial purpose.  I will  greatly appreciate it if you connect me to makers of Preservative.  I really  want the Banga Sauce with Preservative that will not have poison or harm.  But can have a duration of about two years outside the refridgerator.

Comment: @OkoroosamudiamenI - there are very few sauces that will last two years outside refrigeration - I'm assuming opened, because for closed storage you can probably just can them, especially with commercial equipment. If you can think of any sauces that last like that, you might contact that company and ask what preservatives they use, or you might look at the ingredients list, and search for manufacturers of any named preservative.  You may or may not be able to use the same methods (if they depend on acidity, or sugar or salt levels), but they should be able to point you in the right direction.